# BATCH: Contar las carpetas dentro de un directorio y devolverlas en una variable

Tags: windows, batch

Necesito un archivo **Batch** (**.BAT**) que lea todas las carpetas de un directorio (sin contar las sub-carpetas) y que las devuelva en una variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por que el -1?. En fin ya lo solucione para el que tenga curiosidad use solo esta  linea:

@Echo off
Dir /ad | find "dirs">dir.txt

For /f "" %%A IN (dir.txt) do if not defined _carpetas set "_carpetas=%%A"

Echo Total carpetas^>%_carpetas%

**Gracias de todos modos ;)**

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /ad /b ^| find /c /v ""') do echo Total carpetas: %%a
```

- El comando `dir /ad /b` genera la lista de carpetas (sin incluir `.` y `..`) Esta lista es filtrada por el comando `find`
- El comando `find` cuenta (`/c`) el número de líneas que no cumplen (`/v`) la  condición de no contener ningún caracter (`""`)
- El resultado es procesado mediante un `for /f` que almacena en `%%a` (el parametro reemplazable indicado) el número de carpetas.